# Подтверждение удаления файла

Tags: php

это скрипт обработчика удаления.Имя файла передаются через поле 'text' посредством POST.Сверяеться имя файла и удаляеться. 
Вот вопрос: как осуществить подтверждение на удаление кнопками "Да" и "Нет" и удалять? Заранее благодарен)

```
<?php

$dir = "./gallery";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { $name=$_POST['del'];

unlink ($dir.'/'.$name);
print 'Удален файл' . $name;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$dir = "./gallery";
if(isset($_POST['del'])){$name=$_POST['del'];}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
print("Точно?!");
?>
<!-- index.php - ссылка на ваш скрипт. Туда же, куда приходит $_POST['submit'] и $_POST['del']-->
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="confirm_del" value="1">ДА</button>
<button type="submit" name="confirm_del" value="0">НЕТ</button>
<input type="hidden" name="del" value="<?=$_POST['del']?>" />
</form>
<?php
}
if(isset($_POST['confirm_del'])){
    if($_POST['confirm_del']==1){
        unlink ($dir.'/'.$name); 
        print 'Удален файл ' . $name;
    }else{
        print 'Спасен файл ' . $name;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: При любой нажатой кнопке надпись-"Спасен файл";
а имя файла не пишет.

Comment: Мой косяк. Поправил: === на == и проверку имени файла

Comment: Вот спасибо огромное)

Comment: Там есть галочка, если ответ принят. ;)